# How to get URL in WebView of each page

Tags: android, url, android-webview

Is it possible to get the URL from address bar in Webview, Android. In my app there is a webview and I want to download that link in address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
webview.getOriginalUrl();
```

Read more [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getOriginalUrl%28%29)